# Scroll Content Layer Underneath position:absolute Layer?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a parent div that has a div within it with absolute positioning that overlays a semi-transparent layer of color over the entirety of the parent. This color layer has a content layer underneath it that overflows the parent div's size, and thus, needs to be scrollable. However, because of the position:absolute element preceding it, I cannot seem to scroll the content at all.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
  <div style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"></div>
  <p>content content content content content content content 
     content content content content content content content</p>
</div>
```

I initially attempted to have the parent element be relatively positioned, but this in turn caused the layer to scroll with the content. How can I change this structure or css such that the content is still scrollable despite the position:absolute overlay? (**and yes, I want the layer on a separate element**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding the following CSS to your absolutely positioned element: `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: You know, I kept wondering in my head if that would work but didn't bother to try it. This works for my initial case! Thanks!